# Counting records in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im having trouble coming up with a way of counting distinct record for a particular table and needing a little help with this. For example say have i have the following

```
         FIRSTNAME      LASTNAME     STATE
           WILL           SMITH        PA
           JOHN           DOE          PA
           BOB            THOMAS       OH
           TOM            JONES        OH
           MARK           TIMMS        CA
```

What I am looking for is a count of the distinct states in this table. Im looking for a count of 3.

Here what I have so far, but getting syntax error

```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONFIG) AS total
   FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are using to retrieve those records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the correct count of 3:

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT State
    FROM yourTable
)
```

In MS Access you typically have to get the Distinct records first, then then the count of those records. See the below article for some tips on Distinct Counts.

[Microsoft Access Tips & Tricks: Distinct Counts](http://blogannath.blogspot.com/2010/02/microsoft-access-tips-tricks-distinct.html)